# Symfony2 - bug with storing sessions in memcache (security context becomes empty)

Tags: php, session, symfony, memcached

I have a bug with storing sessions in memcache.

The bug is reproduced, if I log in and try to open around 25 different pages at the same time (different tabs). Sometimes my user gets logged out. The funny thing is that the session is kept, but security context is removed. And even funnier thing is that this security context is restored (probably with other request). And the funniest thing is that if I set default filesystem session storage - everything works as expected.

Sessions are stored on Amazon Elasticache.

If I check my user session on Amazon during those requests - there happens something like this:

- Request 1 - My session has `sf2_` attributes key and `_security_main` key
- Request 2 - My session has `sf2_` attributes key and `_security_main` key
- Request 3 - My session has only `sf2_` key
- Request 4 - My session has `sf2_` attributes key and `_security_main` key **AGAIN**

I believe it has something to do with the concurrency.

I've tried lot different things, but I am out of ideas currently. Any tips are much appreciated!

---

#### Technical info

- Symfony version 2.1.0-DEV
- [security.yml](http://pastebin.com/V37EFBTY)

Please, let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by the different time, configured for php script execution time and memcache session lock. I had 60 seconds for php and 15 seconds for `memcache.session_lock`

So, what happened under the hood:

- Script A starts, locks session, takes up to 60 seconds
- Script B starts, waits for session to be unlocked
- After 15 seconds of Script A execution, memcache unlocks session.
- Script B intrudes in the flow and "corrupts" the session

So I have increased `memcache.session_lock` time to match php execution time - and the problem had gone.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony 2.1 is End of Maintenance. This means no bug fixes anymore, only security fixes until End of Life in 11/2013.

You should update to Symfony 2.3 LTS, which has a maintenance period of 36 months. Maybe this is already fixed. If not, raise an [issue in the project](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues).

Btw. you can try the `memcached` handler instead of `memcache`. Mentioned in [#8407](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/8407)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'd like to have a bug defined before updating a project to the newer version. It is not that easy no update it

Comment: I know, 'cause of some mandatory changes and BC breaks in 2.3 there is something to do before upgrading. But it's worth it and if you have done it, you have a long period of not have to upgrading, since 2.3 is a Long Term Support version.

Comment: Btw. you can do an intermediate upgrade to the latest 2.2 version, which has no BC breaks and a maintenance period (including bugfixes) 'til 11/2013